# UIImagePickerController Camera Not saving Photos in Photo Library

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uiimagepickercontroller

Has anyone ever had this problem before? I'm using the `UIImagePickerController` Camera to take photos with my application, and I noticed the photos are not being stored in the photo library after being taken. I've tried it both on iOS5 with the iPhone4 and iOS6 with the iPhone5 and same result. Here is how I'm setting it up:

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
{
    imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
}

imagePickerController.delegate = self;
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES];
[imagePickerController release];
```

Seems as though the UIImagePickerController should implicitly save a photo that's taken to the users photo library? Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: hello @CoDEFRo I have recently edited my answer please try it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try following code.

```
-(IBAction)useCamera
{
 if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:
      UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
 {
  UIImagePickerController *imagePicker =
  [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
  imagePicker.delegate = self;
  imagePicker.sourceType =
  UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
  imagePicker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                            (NSString *) kUTTypeImage,
                            nil];
  imagePicker.allowsEditing = NO;
  [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
  newMedia = YES;
 }
}

#pragma mark- camera picker delegate methods

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
 NSString *mediaType = [info
                        objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];

 [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

 if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage]) {
  UIImage *image = [info
                    objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

  [imageView setAutoresizingMask:(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth)];
  imageView.image = image;
  if (newMedia)
   UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image,
                                  self,
                                  @selector(image:finishedSavingWithError:contextInfo:),
                                  nil);
 }
 else if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie])
 {
  // Code here to support video if enabled
 }
}

-(void)image:(UIImage *)image
finishedSavingWithError:(NSError *)error
 contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo
{
 if (error) {
  UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                        initWithTitle: @"Save failed"
                        message: @"Failed to save image"\
                        delegate: nil
                        cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                        otherButtonTitles:nil];
  [alert show];
 }
}
```

Pick photo from camera and store it to ImageView and call save method to save it to camera roll.
 May this will help

Comment: Thanks for the response. So, the camera for the UIImagePickerController will not implicitly save the photo to your photo library? This doesn't seem correct to me.

Comment: Nope, you have to add these methods yourself (the code above seems correct). The call to `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum` is the part that actually saves to the photo library.

Comment: @RicardoRendonCepeda - Thanks. So then UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera should or shouldn't return an asset for the photo that was just taken? Because my problem isn't so much that the photo isn't in the library, it's that the asset is returning nil for some reason and I can't extract the thumbnail from it and can't use it to load the image aynchronously.

Comment: sourceType just defines where your image picker gets its media from. The above code checks that the device has a camera, then proceeds to launch an image picker object which uses the camera. If it's returning nil then this means it isn't detecting a camera on the device.

Comment: @RicardoRendonCepeda - Thanks for the response. Sorry I actually meant UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL.

Comment: Hi @CoDEFRo, i know you marked this answer as correct, so here is the actual source code with detailed explanation so you can understand what you are `copy-paste`ing: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Accessing_the_iPhone_Camera_and_Photo_Library_(iOS_6)